# Setting up an asymmetric frustum in VTK in python

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I have a large image/scene, and I want to render smaller parts of that image, something like the blue dotted area here:

[image]

That means I have an asymmetric frustum, which I've also heard referred to as an "oblique viewing plane" or "principal point offset". (Skew would also be asymmetric, but this isn't skewed.) I know the world coordinates of all the points of interest, but I'm having trouble setting up the camera parameters in VTK. I have tried:

1. `SetScreenBottomLeft`, `SetScreenBottomRight` and `SetScreenTopRight`, but using `GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix` didn't work:

```
cptm = camera.GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix(
    aspect_ratio,
    camera.GetClippingRange()[0],
    camera.GetClippingRange()[1]
)    
viewport_coords = cptm.MultiplyPoint(np.append(world_coords_bottom_left, 1))
viewport_coords_normalised = np.array(viewport_coords[:-1]) / viewport_coords[-1]
camera.SetScreenBottomLeft(viewport_coords_normalised)
```

2. Using `vtkCoordinate` to do the transform didn't work either:

```
coordinate = vtkCoordinate()
coordinate.SetCoordinateSystemToWorld()
coordinate.SetValue(world_coords_bottom_left)
coords = coordinate.GetComputedViewportValue(renderer)
bottom_left_norm = np.append(np.array(coords) / np.array(resolution), 0.5)
camera.SetScreenBottomLeft(bottom_left_norm)
```

I find it confusing that the `SetScreen...` methods only seem to take effect after `SetUseOffAxisProjection(True)`. But just calling `SetUseOffAxisProjection(True)` without shifting the screen corners already seems to modify the rendering (even if camera position, focal point and ViewUp are unchanged, and even if I set the EyeAngle to 0). I've looked into [the C++ code](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/e4892a2e936fad8266cb515bbb73ef1a908a9c8f/Rendering/Core/vtkCamera.cxx), and can't figure out why that would happen.

3. calculating the explicit projection transform matrix myself, and using

```
camera.SetExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix(projection_matrix) 
camera.SetUseExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix(True)
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I enter for the `projection_matrix`. Even completely random numbers don't change what is rendered.

I'd appreciate if anybody can point me to where I might be going wrong, or an example where it has been done before, or an idea for how to troubleshoot further.